# How to structure database in mongoose for analytics

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, analytics

in my node.js app users are able to post downloadable content. Making them able to see how many downloads were performed is easy, but I'd like to create a dashboard for the users with a chart showing the downloads in a graph using d3.js). How to smartly structure my mongo database ? It should be flexible but small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here. 10gen has made a real case for analytics with Mongo.
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/
http://www.mongodb.com/events/analytics-with-mongodb-dataversity

Comment: Thank you. With mongoose I'll need to use the mixed type won't i ?